# Странное поведение regexp'ов

Tags: python, регулярные-выражения

Чем объясняется подобное поведение регулярок в питоне? Я не эксперт, но по логике вещей результат должен быть одинаковый.

```
>>> q = re.compile(r'\".\"')
>>> q.match('asdf"s"asdf').group()
AttributeError
>>> q.match('"s"asdf').group()
"s"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

http://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html#re.match

If zero or more characters at the **beginning of string**

в вашем случае или используйте search или шаблон должен быть r'.*(\".\")'

Comment: Такой шаблон из первого варианта ловит asdf"s", если match использовать. Search работает как надо, спасибо!